# How to implement STDOUT and file write based on parameter input

Tags: python, file, stdout

I have the input file that looks like **[this](http://dpaste.com/1RBSWR5.txt)** (infile.txt):

```
a x
b y
c z
```

I want to implement a program that enable user to write to STDOUT or file depending on the command:

```
python mycode.py infile.txt outfile.txt
```

Will write to file.

And with this

```
python mycode.py infile.txt #2nd case
```

Will write to STDOUT.

I'm stuck with this code:

```
import sys
import csv

nof_args = len(sys.argv)
infile  = sys.argv[1]

print nof_args
outfile = ''
if nof_args == 3:
    outfile = sys.argv[2]

# for some reason infile is so large
# so we can't save it to data structure (e.g. list) for further processing
with open(infile, 'rU') as tsvfile:
    tabreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter=' ')

    with open(outfile, 'w') as file:
        for line in tabreader:
            outline = "__".join(line)
            # and more processing
            if nof_args == 3:
                file.write(outline + "\n")
            else:
                print outline
    file.close()
```

When using 2nd case it produces

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    with open(outfile, 'w') as file:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

What's the better way to implement it?

Comment: Did you define `outfile` to `stdout` when `nof_args == 2`? Otherwise `with open(outfile, 'w') as file:` will fail.

Comment: I see you've used my `len(sys.argv)` from the question you deleted. Do you make a habit of deleting questions once you have an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import sys

if write_to_file:
    out = open(file_name, 'w')
else:
    out = sys.stdout

# or a one-liner:
# out = open(file_name, 'w') if write_to_file else sys.stdout

for stuff in data:
    out.write(stuff)

out.flush() # cannot close stdout

# Python deals with open files automatically
```

You can also use this instead of `out.flush()`:

```
try:
    out.close()
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

This looks a bit ugly to me, so, `flush` will be just well.

Comment: Can you elaborate with my example for-loop and `sys.argv`?

Comment: @neversaint, just put any calls to `out.write` inside the loop.

Comment: @neversaint, in almost the same way: open the file for reading or use `sys.stdin`, but don't `flush` and use the second method provided in the answer to attempt to close the file. You should also substitute `write` for `read`.